# should I declare my object global or static?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I draw random numbers using `<random>` from C++11. I do it by creating an instance `obj` of the following class (for the interested reader: It is taken from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918758/how-to-make-each-thread-use-its-own-rng-in-c11/15919785?noredirect=1#comment22687933_15919785)):

```
class RNG
{
public:
    typedef std::mt19937 Engine;
    typedef std::uniform_real_distribution<double> Distribution;


    double operator()()
    {
        return distribution(engine);
    }
    Engine engine;
    Distribution distribution;
};
```

Calling `obj()` gives me the desired random number. Now, I have three functions that all have to use `obj`. Declaring `obj` global would work, but is it also correct? Or are there other (more correct) alternatives?

Comment: A member `static` **is** a global, don't kid yourself.

Comment: Correctness of globals depends on the rest of the program. I'd pass an RNG to each function that needs one, that makes deterministic tests possible.

Comment: I just wanted to ask the same. Usually the only difference between global and static (in some programming languages) is that static is not everywhere visible, but both are living all the time.

Comment: All three function could use separate instances of the class. Or use a global variable. If the functions are in the same source file you could make an anonymous (unnamed) namespace containing the instance, or even a global static instance.

Comment: If instances produce different random numbers (somehow different seeding or **real** real random numbers) then it would not matter to define multiple objects or just one. The class is small enough to define multiple if it helps to stay loose coupled. Otherwise access one global one. Up to your, which structure feels better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If the part of your program that works with `RNG` consists of and will likely consist of (hard to see the future though) just those three functions, and those functions only need to work on one object - always the same, all the time-, then why not making that object global.

Avoid restricting a *type* to only have one instance (Singleton pattern) unless that is an inherent characteristic of that type. If *your program* uses only one instance of `RNG`, then *your program will just create one instance* (i.e., make the object global, or constrain your program - not the type - to only create one instance). I can very well imagine that other libraries or programs may create several random generators.

Of course, if one day those functions will have to work on *several* different instances of `RNG` (although one at a time), then you will need to let them take an instance of that class as a function argument, and let them work on that argument. Clients will have to take care of providing the appropriate instance of `RNG` as an argument to those functions.

Then, if one day you will realize that those functions will also end up all working on other object types, and those data are somehow related to each other, you could consider wrapping them in a data structure or in a class, possibly making your functions *member functions* of that class - if the operation it carries out is *fundamental* for that type.

Giving guidelines in general without knowing what you have in mind, and what kind of application or library you are going to write, is not easy. Hopefully this helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will put more thoughts into the overall structure of my programs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use singleton pattern.

Just add one method:

```
 static RNG& inst()
 {
     static RNG instance;
     return instance;
 }
```

And disable copying of your object:

```
private:
    RNG(const RNG&); // without implementation
    RNG& operator=(const RNG&); // without implementation
```

Then you can access to your instance:

```
d = RNG::inst()();
```

Comment: +1 for the easiest and most beautiful design pattern: Singleton. Improves software quality so much. And nice way to use static here instead of a check for null/nothing, since that check adds the requirement to deal with racing problems

Comment: @Amegon Most overused and dangerous pattern trying to hide bad design, you mean?

Comment: Wait, why can't we have more than one random number generator?

Comment: Singletons should only really be used when there is a legitimate reason for why only one instance of the object can exist (Like, maybe a logger? Or a graphics engine interface?) as opposed to compensating for bad design.

Comment: Using `static` replaces initialization race problems with order of destruction problems.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes, Probably because it should be seeded once and then get next randoms

Comment: The entire object is `static` there is no pointer hence the static instance would be properly initialized before first call to `inst()`, so no multi thread issues I think

Comment: @AbhijitKadam I believe there are potential issues with multi-threading using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069255/singleton-multi-threading (It is thread-safe in C++11 though, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-singleton-pattern-thread-safe)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz dangerous design, because people use it like global variables? SlxS, thanks for the explanation. So if it is a large class with much initialization code, then a Singleton would be okay?

Comment: @ SlxS In that example the pointer is `static` the object is not. Here the entire object is static and should be initialized before the `main()`. However the object will stay lifetime.

Comment: @Amegon Because it has exactly the same problems global variables have, but it covers them instead of solving them. Singleton has very limited real-world usage.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz If a Singleton is defined inside a class or any custom namespace, doesn't this prevent the biggest risk of global variables? (the risk that another class defines the same name, leading to unexpected results)?

Comment: That's not the biggest risk of global variables. Anyway, it's not about the "risk". It's about bad design.